# Input Accessory View Realization

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-controls

Absolutely beginner obj-c question.
I am totally frustrated last few days about to do my task, but it seems like I have a problem bigger than my level of knowledges now. Before posting this question I asked few times about this in different forms, but so far I haven't understanding of how to do it, so I search for turnkey solution.

Task:

Plain UITableView with two sections. I am interested only in first section to improve Input Accessory View to switch between four textFields in cells. 
http://uaimage.com/image/62f08045

Custom cells are inherited from UITableViewCell and have a UITextField's in them as a property. So my task is to set first responder to different textFields.

Ideas:

- to set textFields as a delegate for ViewController and then resign and set first responder in input acessory view methods
- to tag textFields, set NSMutableArray filled with this textFields and then in -inputAccessoryViewNext and in -inputAccesoryViewPrev change responder
- to tag cells by indexPath and get textFields from cell

But I'm unable to realize any of this advances correctly and nothing works for me yet, so very need help.
I'm attached UITableViewController.m and FDTextFieldCell.m (custom cell) above:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5rYA7McNhFlSXBrLTFVU2hVd1U

Will be glad to reward anyone who can help by a modest bounty of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second idea is the right approach.  Add an instance variable to your table view controller like `NSMutableArray *_textFields` and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`.

Then, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, add something like this every time you :

```
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        FDTextFieldCell *cell = [self textFieldCell];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Ваше Имя"];
        [[cell textField] setPlaceholder:@"Обязательно"];
        [[cell textField] setText:[profile name]];

        [[cell textField] setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
        [[cell textField] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];

        // ADD THIS
        [[cell textField] setTag:[indexPath row]];
        if (![_textFields containsObject:[cell textField]]) {
            [_textFields addObject:[cell textField]];
            [_textFields sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tag" ascending:YES]]];
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

From there, you have a sorted array of your text fields, so you can implement your accessory methods like so:

```
- (void) inputAccessoryViewDidSelectNext:(FDInputAccessoryView *)view {
    UITextField *textField = nil;
    for (textField in _textFields) {
        if ([textField isFirstResponder])
            break;
    }

    NSInteger indexOfFirstResponder = [_textFields indexOfObject:textField];
    NSInteger nextIndex = indexOfFirstResponder + 1;
    if (nextIndex == [_textFields count])
        nextIndex = 0;

    UITextField *nextField = [_textFields objectAtIndex:nextIndex];
    [nextField becomeFirstResponder];    
}

- (void) inputAccessoryViewDidSelectPrev:(FDInputAccessoryView *)view {
    UITextField *textField = nil;
    for (textField in _textFields) {
        if ([textField isFirstResponder])
            break;
    }

    NSInteger indexOfFirstResponder = [_textFields indexOfObject:textField];
    NSInteger previousIndex = indexOfFirstResponder - 1;
    if (previousIndex < 0)
        previousIndex = [_textFields count] - 1;

    UITextField *previousField = [_textFields objectAtIndex:previousIndex];
    [previousField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joe, for trying to help! But in your solution I have a same issue that in my code: in -inputAccessoryViewDidSelectNext: log shows that array count equal 0 and I can't get into if statement, so this code isn't working yet. Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Are you sure the `[_textFields addObject:[cell textField]];` portion of your table view cell method is getting called?  And are you sure that `_textFields` has been initialized (i.e. is non-nil)?